# Playing a specific song when a user calling a command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

so what I am trying to reach is when a user call a `!song1` command the bot will play the specified YouTube URL for this command, I do not want any kind of search just playing the YouTube URL I put in the code, please see the code below I know it is old and I am looking for something new and no errors in future, and I am really beginner in coding bots.

I hope I explain this issue successfully, thanks in advance.

---

song1.js

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
module.exports = {
    commands: 'song1',
    callback: (message) => {

        const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/song1url';

        if (message.content == '!song1') {
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("you should be on a vc");
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then(VoiceConnection => {
                VoiceConnection.play(ytdl(url)).on("finish", () =>
                    VoiceConnection.disconnect());
               
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Now Playing: song1')
                    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setColor('#447a88')




                message.reply(embed)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any errors? What is wrong with the above?

Comment: thank you for your reply, well the only thing I am facing right now is some commands when it get called the bot disconnected from the voice room, although the other commands are works perfectly, I checked the urls it might be broken or something but it seems I am missing something.